# JAVA Esapi encoder

Tags: java, escaping, esapi

Hello I'm using ESAPI for encoding and decoding strings to avoid script attacks and I'm using it like this:

```
   public static String encode(String value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Encoder encoder = ESAPI.encoder();
    return encoder.encodeForHTML(encoder.canonicalize(value));
}
```

The problem is if I pass String with "%" sign, and decode using *StringEscapeUtils* *unescapeHtml* it changes "%" to � should I use different method for unescaping ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this seems to be an issue with ESAPI defaultencoder canonilize method, just found one issue tracker in mentioned GitHub link 
https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java/issues/1

Comment: The actual issue you want is https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/issues/377 but it doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in using `Encoder.canonicalize()` as you're doing here.  canonicalize before input validation, not before output.

Just use the encoding methods here, do not use the canonicalize method.

Other wise suggestions for canonicalize:

1. Do not persist the canonicalized value.  Only use it to perform
   validation logic against.  Meaning, RawInput->Canonicalize->Validate.  If validated, persist/process the original value.
2. The main advantage of the method is in detection of mixed or
   multiple encoding attacks.